# Strange behavior in MASM: "dec" directive causes subtraction by 2

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am writing a program to display the current time and date for 10 seconds. I am directed that i may ONLY use smallwin.inc for this. I wrote a program that works using Irvine32.inc, but when i switch to ONLY smallwin, i needed to write some procedures for outputting numbers. When i added these, a VERY STRANGE behavior began to happen! I use the call "dec repTime" and it will decrease by 2 instead of 1! I have tried "sub repTime, 1" and it still does the same! I have even moved repTime to eax, then subtracted 1, then moved eax back to repTime, it still subtracts 2!

The program i wrote is supposed to run for 10 seconds. Because of the subtract 2 issue, it runs for 4 seconds instead! What is wrong?!?

Here is my code:

```
; this code demonstrates the usage of Windows API functions to display
; current date and time. It provides a running digital clock that updates
; itself for 10 seconds. The output is displayed starting with cursor position
; (5,5) and uses yellow foreground and blue background.

INCLUDE smallwin.inc

.data
buffer DB 256 DUP(?)
prompt    BYTE "Today is: "                  ; strings used to format the output
slash     BYTE '/'
colon     BYTE ':'
space     BYTE "     Time: "
newLine   WORD 0D0Ah                         
repTime   DWORD 10                           ; display time for 10 seconds   
cursPos   COORD <5,5>                        ; cursor coordinates

.data?
outHandle DWORD ?                            ; storage for console output handle
sysTimeNow   SYSTEMTIME <>                      ; storage for system time structure
sysTimeFuture SYSTEMTIME <>

.code

WriteChar PROC

pushfd
pushad
mov  buffer,al
INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, OFFSET buffer, 1, 0, 0

popad
popfd
ret
WriteChar ENDP

outInt PROC USES eax ebx ecx edx,
number: SDWORD               ; method parameter
mov ebx, 10                ; divisor for the radix system
xor ecx, ecx               ; digits counter
cmp number, 0              ; is number >= 0?
jge go                      ; yes - proceed
neg number                 ; negate the number
mov al, '-'
INVOKE WriteChar

go:
mov eax, number   
puDigit:
xor edx, edx
div ebx                    ; get one digit
push edx                   ; save it for further processing
inc ecx                    ; update the digits counter
cmp eax, 0                 ; end of processing
jne puDigit

printIT:
pop eax                     ; get a digit from stack
or al, 30h                 ; ASCII conversion
INVOKE WriteChar           ; print it
loop printIT

ret
outInt ENDP

format2 PROC 
LOCAL zero:BYTE

mov zero, '0'
cmp ax, 10                              ; number < 10 ?
jge L 
push eax                                ; YES - output preceeding 0
INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, ADDR zero, 1, 0, 0
pop eax
L:   INVOKE outInt, eax                          ; output the number itself

ret
format2 ENDP


main PROC
INVOKE GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
mov outHandle, eax                      ; get console handle for output

INVOKE SetConsoleTextAttribute, outHandle, 30 ; setup colors
INVOKE GetLocalTime, ADDR sysTimeFuture

;set Future Time to Dec 25, 2013
mov sysTimeFuture.wDay, 25
mov sysTimeFuture.wMonth, 12
mov sysTimeFuture.wYear, 2013
mov sysTimeFuture.wHour, 0
mov sysTimeFuture.wMinute, 0
mov sysTimeFuture.wSecond, 0


startLabel:
INVOKE SetConsoleCursorPosition, outHandle, cursPos

INVOKE GetLocalTime, ADDR sysTimeNow       ; retrieve current date/time

INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, ADDR prompt,
SIZEOF prompt, 0, 0                  ; output prompt

mov eax, 0
mov ax, sysTimeNow.wDay                    ; day of the month
call format2
INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, ADDR slash, 1, 0, 0 ; output '/'

mov ax, sysTimeNow.wMonth                  ; month number
call format2
INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, ADDR slash, 1, 0, 0 ; output '/'

mov ax, sysTimeNow.wYear                   ; print out the year
INVOKE outInt, ax
INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, ADDR space, SIZEOF space, 0, 0 

mov ax, sysTimeNow.wHour                   ; output hours
call format2
INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, ADDR colon, 1, 0, 0 ; output ':'

mov ax, sysTimeNow.wMinute                 ; output minutes
call format2
INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, ADDR colon, 1, 0, 0 ; output ':'

mov ax, sysTimeNow.wSecond                 ; output seconds
call format2

INVOKE Sleep, 1000                      ; wait for 1 second
dec repTime                             ; update the stop watch counter
jnz startLabel

INVOKE SetConsoleTextAttribute, outHandle, 15 ; reset the colors 
INVOKE WriteConsole, outHandle, ADDR newLine, 2, 0, 0 ; start new line
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0 
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: How did you observe this? By stepping through the code in a debugger..?

Comment: No, if you run the program, it will only run for 4 seconds. I did do "INVOKE outInt, repTime" after the dec statement, and you can see each second that the clock goes up by 1 second and the value of repTime decreases by 2.

Comment: Placing an invoke outInt before and after the decrement shows that the decrement does in fact decrease by only 1, but somehow before the statement is reached again, it is decremented EXTRA. If you output, decrement, then output in a loop, expected behavior should be some output like "5,4 4,3 3,2 2,1", where the spaces seperate each loop, however, the output is actually "5,4 3,2 1,0" meaning that the decrement works properly but somehow this memory address is being messed with somewhere else!

Comment: Place a memory write watchpoint on it in your debugger and see who is messing with it.

Comment: Here is a hint, your problem lies in your `outInt` proc.

Comment: The only thing i could think of was that i somehow raised the carry flag or something, but putting "clc" in front of the dec command doesnt change anything. Is it some other flag that im not aware of?

Comment: I looked here: http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/lecture.html#I77_0070_eflags_bits and the only thing i can see would affect a dec or inc directive would be carry flag. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the prototype for `outint`:

```
outInt PROTO number:SDWORD
```

The parameter expected is a **S** igned **DWORD** - `SDWORD` or it could be `DWORD`, does not matter, look what you are passing as a parameter:

```
mov     ax, sysTimeNow.wYear                   ; print out the year
INVOKE  outInt, ax
```

You are passing a `WORD` sized register as a parameter, and your using `eax` in the procedure.

Change the above two lines to:

```
movzx   eax, sysTimeNow.wYear                   ; print out the year
INVOKE  outInt, eax
```

or:

```
xor     eax, eax
mov     ax, sysTimeNow.wYear                   ; print out the year
INVOKE  outInt, eax
```

Which will "zero out" the upper half of `eax` and make it work.  Or, what you could do, is make the procedure expect a `WORD` sized parameter since that is what you are passing, and use `ax` instead of `eax` in the proc.

Comment: I think i understand now. It is intended to look at more space in memory than i am giving it.... and it probably so happens that the next area in memory happens to be that repTime variable, so it fiddles with its values a little bit. Thank you very much!

Comment: I did decide to zero-extend the move and use the whole eax register by the way. :)